# Making use of binary search algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm more interested in the thought process than in the code itself. I'm supposed to find the number of ***v[i]*** components in a sorted array such that ***x < v[i] < y***, where ***x*** and ***y*** are sent as input from the keyboard. 
I'm supposed to solve this efficiently using a modified binary search instead of a regular search through the vector.

My problem is that I can't visualize how to implement a binary search in this case, the method just doesn't seem fit to me.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Is the array `v` sorted?

Comment: Yes it is, I forgot to mention that, thanks a lot !

Comment: Just find the node `v[i]` then tranverse the tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do a binary search in the array for `x` and `y`. Then you could subtract the index of `x` from the index of `y` to get how many items are between them.

You'd actually have to subtract 1 from that result since you are using strictly less-than.

For example, say you have an array:

```
[3, 6, 8, 10, 14, 39, 41, 100]
```

Let x=8 and y = 39.

The index of x is 2 and the index of y is 5.

5-2 = 3

3-1 = 2

If `x` and `y` are allowed to be values that are not contained in your array, you can still follow the same approach. Search for `x` and if it is not found, use the index of the element that is just larger than x. Likewise for the index of the element that is just smaller than `y`.

Comment: Well what if x and y are not in the array ?

Comment: @user43389 You have to find the nearest above (`x < v[i]`) and below (`v[i] < y`) anyway. And once you have found one of the limits, you can use that in the binary search for the other limit.

Comment: Got the idea, thanks a lot, I'm not quite sure on how to go about the coding part, but I guess it can't be that hard. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @user43389 If you know how to do binary search, it's exactly the same thing. Just call your binary search function twice with two different values, `x` and `y`. Then just subtract the indices.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the original array v is sorted, just follow those steps:

1. Use binary search to locate value x in the array - if it's not there (the lower and upper bounds in binary search meet), get the index of closest higher value
2. Do the same for the y value, get the index of closest lower value if it's not this time
3. Find out how many items are in between (by subtracting indices and adding 1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great article if you're interested: [Binary Search](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch)

Depending on the values of `x` and `y`, if they're the lower and upper limits respectively of numbers within the array, it's as simple as applying a general BS algorithm with those limits in place rather than the general first and last element of the array.

Drawing it up on paper will help.